# How separate thread (which could be started/stopped from any activity) could handle orientation changes?

Tags: android, multithreading

How to have a thread which is not dependent on special activity, it could be started/stopped from any activity and start from background downloader, and need to handle orientation changes?

The task is, to start downloader from main thread,but before starting the download I need to fetch resources in separate thread and soon as the process of fetching resources is complete it's return main thread and start downloading process, and as soon as the downloading process is complete could start the process of fetching resources and downloading, the problem I don't know what to use to implement the part of fetching data and then returning to main thread ,from where I'll start downloader. I use for downloading Glide,it's need to start from main thread.it's unclear the first part if I use IntentService in that case when its done its job its return to main thread , but it could be any activity, while  I don' t want to call Glide from any activity, assuming that any activity could be receiver when the service is completed.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a service to me, especially if you don't need to interact with the UI, but even so you could do that with the help of a LocalBroadcastManager. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @Alex I have updated my question

Comment: Ok, you will definitely need to look at using Handlers and how they are using the post method for inter thread communication and communication with the main thread https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html. If you are brave padawan I would really suggest at looking at Reactive Extensions, they are made for this kind of use cases, but they have quite a steep learning curve.

Comment: Ok , the sample RX provide are all started from UI thread and return results to UI. I could not find RX sample that are not attached to specified activity, and are working for whole application, if you could give any advise concerning Rx samples ,could be great.